# PHP_SELF dont work in same page

Tags: php

I want to use it in `/index.php?page=2` but when I press the submit button it throws me in `index.php`

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

In `index.php` I have

```
<?php
switch($_GET['page']){
case 1:
include_once('/p/fizika.php');
break;
case 2:
include_once('/p/geom.php');
break;
case 3:
include_once('/p/algebra.php');
break;
default:
include_once('/p/algebra.php');
break;
}
?>
```

Please help me.

Comment: I highly recommend not using PHP_SELF.

Comment: `<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">` ... why my kodz redirect to haxorz site? oh no! my kodz haxed! please help! **but seriously though, don't use PHP_SELF ...**

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the form to send the browser to the current page, try this:

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

As others have said, `REQUEST_URI` is another way to do this, but you should always be careful to sanitize it using [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or similar, since its contents are partially under the user's control (and so could expose you to [injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#Malevolent)).

Answer (score 3):

PHP_SELF returns the "filename of the currently executing script, relative to the document root". 
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

If you need to know the full URI, use:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

If you just want the form to submit to itself (same page) just use

```
<form action="">
```